# splunk query for counting based on regex

Tags: regex, logging, splunk

My sample log looks like below

```
fixed message: 443-343-234-event-put
fixed message: wre-sdfsdf-234-event-keep-alive
fixed message: dg34-343-234-event-auth_revoked
fixed message: qqqq-sdf-234-event-put
fixed message: wre-r323-234-event-keep-alive
fixed message: we33-343-234-event-auth_revoked
```

log pattern is `"fixed message: {UUID}-{event-type}"`

I would like to capture how many total events; out of those how many are event-put, event-keep-alive and event-auth_revoked

can I have splunk query to capture above needs ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use [rex](http://docs.splunk.com/Documentation/Splunk/6.2.5/SearchReference/rex) to prototype a field extraction, so you can try it out first

```
rex "fixed message: (?P<UUID>\w+-\w+\w+)-(?P<event>.*)"
```

So you can do this:

*search terms* `| rex "fixed message: (?P<UUID>[^-+]-[^-+]-[^-+])-(?P<event>.*)" | stats count by event`

Then you can read the [documentation](http://docs.splunk.com/Documentation/Splunk/6.2.5/Knowledge/Createandmaintainsearch-timefieldextractionsthroughconfigurationfiles) to make it where you don't need to always do the rex command with your searches. So the field extraction happens automatially.