# How to convert "OR" result to line chart

Tags: splunk, splunk-query

I have a query to get the browser info for every event.

```
"http://" index=web GET (Chrome OR Safari OR IE OR Firefox)
```

How can I convert the result to a line chart to get browser usage based on different browsers? I can create line chart for each browser but I want to show the usage on the same chart.

Answer (score 1):

The browser should be a `Field` (check your log body to find field name).
If this is a case you need to pipe a stats count statement, for example :

```
"http://" AND index=web | stats count by `browser`
```

(we assume that Field name is `browser`)

Visualization will give you the chart view.

Comment: The problem is browser information is part of another filed like useragent: some information/chrome(can be IE, Firefox....)/version...... If I count by useragent, it will count all the useragent  not specific browser.

Comment: and why don't you use a regex?Check this : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32359316/splunk-query-for-counting-based-on-regex and the count like : | stats count as mycount by browser